Change default/native resolution of a display in macOS
I have a Philips 55PUS7303/12 TV (albeit it's hooked up to my computer through a Denon AVR-X1400H AV receiver, but this doesn't change the aspect I'm asking about) and it shows up as having a default resolution of 1080p, despite it actually having a native resolution of Ultra HD 4K.
What accentuates this problem is that when trying to use a custom HiDPI resolution (the display isn't considered HiDPI by default) that isn't 1080p, it will be scaled to 1080p, not 4K. So the idea is to somehow configure macOS to think that the display's default resolution is actually 3840x2160 and thus scale any HiDPI resolution to it.
